# IF ELSE In Column Selection

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query that make balance sheet is SAP Business one. 
I have a sum calculation in there and I want it to be like that:

```
if SUM(T1.Credit-T1.Debit) > 0
   show the value in column "Positive Total" and in negative total put 0 or something. 
if SUM(T1.Credit-T1.Debit) < 0
  show the value in column "Negative Total" and in "Positive total" put 0  or something.
```

The code is:

```
SELECT T1.Account, Isnull((SELECT SUM(T3.Debit - T3.Credit)
                           FROM OJDT T2
                             INNER JOIN JDT1 T3 ON T2.TransId = T3.TransId
                             INNER JOIN OACT o ON o.AcctCode = T3.Account
                           WHERE DateDiff(dd,T2.RefDate,'20140101') > 0
                             AND T3.Account LIKE T1.Account
                           GROUP BY T3.Account),0) AS 'Opening Balance',
       SUM(T1.Debit) AS 'Debit', 
       SUM(T1.Credit) AS 'Credit',
       SUM(T1.Credit-T1.Debit ) AS 'Positive Total',
       SUM(T1.Credit-T1.Debit ) AS 'Negative Total'
      ,AcctName, GroupMask,Levels,
      (CASE GroupMask
         WHEN 1 THEN 'ASSET'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'LIABILITIES'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'Capital and Reserves'
         WHEN 4 THEN 'Turnover'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'Cost of Sales'
         WHEN 6 THEN 'Operating Costs'
         WHEN 7 THEN 'Non-Operating Income and Expenditure'
         ELSE 'NOT INCLUDED'
       END) [GROUP]
FROM OJDT T0
  INNER JOIN JDT1 T1 ON T0.TransId = T1.TransId
  INNER JOIN OACT T4 ON T4.AcctCode = T1.Account
WHERE T0.RefDate BETWEEN '20150101' AND '20160131'
GROUP BY T1.Account, AcctName, GroupMask, Levels
Having SUM(T1.Debit - T1.Credit) != 0
ORDER BY T1.Account
```

Thanks In advance, 
Almog.

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Sorry, MS SQL. Thanks Again

Comment: you don't get a syntax error from that code? i'm not being judgy  but the code is total mess i can't see the point of the group by part and this ISNULL  really confused me. please at least check your code can and then ask what you need

Comment: Hey, The code runs perfectly fine. the guy below solved my problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
CASE WHEN SUM(T1.Credit-T1.Debit ) > 0 
     THEN SUM(T1.Credit-T1.Debit ) 
     ELSE 0 
END  'Positive Total',
CASE WHEN SUM(T1.Credit-T1.Debit ) < 0 
     THEN SUM(T1.Credit-T1.Debit ) 
     ELSE 0 
END AS 'Negative Total'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your current query as sub query and write a select statement over it.

Also note that, in this case you need to move `Order By` clause to outer query and also you do not need to specify `SUM(T1.Credit - T1.Debit)` twice in inner query!

Try this:

```
SELECT  * ,
    CASE WHEN K.[Total] > 0 THEN K.[Total]
         ELSE 0
    END AS 'Positive Total' ,
    CASE WHEN K.[Total] < 0 THEN K.[Total]
         ELSE 0
    END AS 'Negative Total'
FROM    ( SELECT    T1.Account ,
                ISNULL(( SELECT SUM(T3.Debit - T3.Credit)
                         FROM   OJDT T2
                                INNER JOIN JDT1 T3 ON T2.TransId = T3.TransId
                                INNER JOIN OACT o ON o.AcctCode = T3.Account
                         WHERE  DATEDIFF(dd, T2.RefDate, '20140101') > 0
                                AND T3.Account LIKE T1.Account
                         GROUP BY T3.Account
                       ), 0) AS 'Opening Balance' ,
                SUM(T1.Debit) AS 'Debit' ,
                SUM(T1.Credit) AS 'Credit' ,
                SUM(T1.Credit - T1.Debit) AS 'Total' ,
                --SUM(T1.Credit - T1.Debit) AS 'Negative Total' , 
                AcctName ,
                GroupMask ,
                Levels ,
                ( CASE GroupMask
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'ASSET'
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'LIABILITIES'
                    WHEN 3 THEN 'Capital and Reserves'
                    WHEN 4 THEN 'Turnover'
                    WHEN 5 THEN 'Cost of Sales'
                    WHEN 6 THEN 'Operating Costs'
                    WHEN 7 THEN 'Non-Operating Income and Expenditure'
                    ELSE 'NOT INCLUDED'
                  END ) [GROUP]
      FROM      OJDT T0
                INNER JOIN JDT1 T1 ON T0.TransId = T1.TransId
                INNER JOIN OACT T4 ON T4.AcctCode = T1.Account
      WHERE     T0.RefDate BETWEEN '20150101' AND '20160131'
      GROUP BY  T1.Account ,
                AcctName ,
                GroupMask ,
                Levels
      HAVING    SUM(T1.Debit - T1.Credit) != 0
    ) AS K
 Order By K.Account
```